# Can't append a python array inside if statement

Tags: python, arrays, function, append

I'm trying to create a function that would add couples of integers to an array if some condition is true but my function always returns empty arrays. I tried to print the integers after the condition is verified and it does print them so I guess I'm appending them wrong. What am I doing wrong here ?

```
ans = np.array([[0,0]])
def q6(n):
    for a in range(n):
        for b in range(n):
            if ((a**2+b**2)/(a*b+1))%2 == 0:             
                np.append(ans,[[a,b]], axis=0)     
    return ans
print(q6(10))
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the way the [numpy.append()](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) works. Quoting from the documentation, the method returns *a copy of arr with values appended to axis. Note that append does not occur in-place: a new array is allocated and filled.*

As the method returns `ans`, and each call of `np.append()` returns a new array instead of modifying the `ans` variable itself, you would get the original value of [[0,0]].

Comment: I was just about to say the same thing.

To add to it, you simply need to: ans = np.append(ans,[[a,b]], axis=0)

    
Also, if you are using this in some type of regularly used function, you might want to consider whether you should declare ans inside of the function.

Comment: I understand. Thank you guys